# jQuery animation problem

Tags: jquery, html, sliding

I'm making a hidable div that starts out on the edge of the screen then slides out to the right when a tab is clicked. This part functions as expected, but when I click the tab to make it slide back, it won't do so... any ideas?

**JS:**

```
$( "#closediv" ).hide();
$( "#opendiv" ).click( function(){
    $( "#opendiv" ).animate(
        { left: "+=100px" },
        700,
        "easeOutExpo",
        function(){
            $( "#opendiv" ).hide();
            $( "#closediv" ).show();
        }
    );
});

$( "#closediv" ).click( function(){
    $( "#closediv" ).animate(
        { left: "-=100px" },
        "easeOutExpo",
        700,
        function(){
            $( "#opendiv" ).show();
            $( "#closediv" ).hide();
        }
    );
});
```

**CSS:**

```
#closediv
  {
   display: block;
   width: 30px;
   height: 95px;
   text-indent: -9999px;
   overflow: auto;
   background: url('/aaron.chauvin/sitepics/closediv.png') bottom;
  }

#closediv:hover
  {
   background-position: 0 0;
  }

#opendiv
  {
   opacity: 0.6;
   display: block;
   width: 30px;
   height: 95px;
   text-indent: -9999px;
   overflow: auto;
   background: url('/aaron.chauvin/sitepics/opendiv.png') bottom;
  }

#opendiv:hover
  {
   background-position: 0 0;
  }
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="opendiv" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px; z-index:2;">
</div>
<div id="closediv" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:100px; z-index:2;">
</div>
```

Sorry about my "block" (modified K&R) indent style, I find it easier to follow than the BSD KNF indent style most people use... =P

Edit:
[Test page](http://students.cmps.subr.edu/aaron.chauvin/misc/test.html)

Comment: You seem to like whitespaces a lot  D:

Comment: Your JS formatting just made me seasick. :(

Comment: lol, like I said, sorry about my modified K&R indent style, but I find it far easier to follow than the indent style most ppl use...

Comment: @Aaron - That's all well and good, but consider that nearly everyone on this site doesn't do anything like that. If you want people to help, help them. You can always reformat later. :)

Comment: @Aaron - Also, can you http://jsfiddle.net/ an example?

Comment: That's fairly standard jQuery code formatting. I find it quite readable.

Comment: oh...I'm looking at the edited version! Yea, the original was a bit wonky. ;)

Comment: already have a test page, forgot to link to it...

Comment: @Jared: Duly noted, but if the formatting looks funny in the future it's 'cuz I'm not used to BSD KNF indent style!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you happen to switch `700 and "easeOutExpo"` in #closediv's animate function? If you switch them, the div seems to slide back, but when #opendiv appears, it is back at left:100 To remedy this, you can use:

```
$("#closediv").hide();
$("#opendiv").click(function(){
    $(this).animate({ left: "+=100px" }, 700, "easeOutExpo",function() {
    $(this).hide();
    $("#closediv").show().css('left', 100);
    });
});

$("#closediv").click(function(){
    $(this).animate({ left: "-=100px" }, 700, "easeOutExpo", function() {
    $("#opendiv").css('left', 0).show();
    $("#closediv").hide();
    });
});
```

Here's a JSFiddle Link: [http://jsfiddle.net/RWnqW](http://jsfiddle.net/RWnqW/2/)

Comment: Oooohhh poop, sure did, thanks!!! Dangit, I hate when I make stupid mistakes like that and can't figure out why something's not working!

Answer (score 1):

You can be more dynamic by using : http://jsfiddle.net/BqJeg/5/

```
$( "#closediv" ).hide();
$( "#opendiv" ).click( function(){
    $( "#opendiv" ).animate(
        { left: "+=100px" },
        700,
        "easeOutExpo",
        function(){
            $( "#closediv" ).css('left', $( "#opendiv" ).css('left'));
            $( "#opendiv" ).hide();
            $( "#closediv" ).show();
        }
    );
});

$( "#closediv" ).click( function(){
    $( "#closediv" ).animate(
            { left: "-=100px" },
        700,
        "easeOutExpo",
        function(){
            $( "#opendiv" ).css('left', $( "#closediv" ).css('left'));
            $( "#opendiv" ).show();
            $( "#closediv" ).hide();
        }

    );
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but DFranks's answer was exactly what I was lookin' for, I still gave you a 1up on the reply though! =)